# Using MSBuild to compile for ToolsVersion 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I need to compile for visual studio project using MSBuild for .Net version 3.5. I have downloaded Visual studio 2013 which comes with a tool chain 12.0 which uses .Net version 4.5. I can't install Visual Studio 2008(which comes with .NET version 3.5) because that is not supported on my Windows 7 PC.

I am using following powershell script to do that:-

```
# set environment variables for Visual Studio Command Prompt
pushd 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC'
cmd /c "vcvarsall.bat&set" |
foreach {
  if ($_ -match "=") {
    $v = $_.split("="); set-item -force -path "ENV:\$($v[0])"  -value "$($v[1])"
  }
}
popd
write-host "`nVisual Studio 2010 Command Prompt variables set." -ForegroundColor Yellow

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" 
write-host "** building busdog.sys" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Exec { MSBuild ./filter/busdog.sln /t:clean /ToolsVersion:3.5}
Exec { MSBuild ./filter/busdog.sln /p:Configuration="$conf_driver" /property:Platform="$platform" /ToolsVersion:3.5}
```

If I remove the "/ToolsVersion" setting from my MSBuild command above or set it to 12.0, then my code gets compiled perfectly.

But, with /ToolsVersion option set to 3.5, I keep getting following error:-

> MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component
>   "VCBuild.exe". If the component is not installed, either 1) install
>   the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework
>   3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.[C:\workspace\busdog\filter\busdog.sln]

I already have .NET framework 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5 installed under: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\

Could someone please help with where I might be going wrong ?

Thanks
Manas

Answer (score 0):

The error message already tells you waht to do: install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried doing that as well but I still get the same error. Also, I am not sure why is it asking me for VCBuild.exe, since VCBuild was replaced by MSBuild from Visual Studio 2010. Do you know why that might be happening ?

Comment: Do you have VS2010 installed by chance?

Comment: No, I have VS2013. VS2010 is not supported on Win7.

Comment: Ok, one more question: are you trying to use node.js in some way?

Comment: No, not using Node.js. Just trying to compile a c# program via command line using MSBuild